# Add to VIEW from another table

Tags: mysql, sql-view

I need to find out how to pull user names into a `VIEW` from a different table. I have 3 tables, User, Lead, and Lead_detail. In the users table there is an ID field which is stored in the Created_By field in the Lead table. In the Lead table I have an ID field that is stored in the Lead_detail Lead_ID field.

I have created a `VIEW` to the Lead_detail table which pulls all the info I need but I have found that I don't have the users name in that `VIEW` so I need to `ALTER` my view to add in the users names per lead but I am having trouble with the statement.

Before altering the `VIEW` I wanted to try a `SELECT` statement to see if I get any data,

```
SELECT * FROM Lead_detail 
JOIN Lead 
ON Lead_detail.lead_id = Lead.id
WHERE Lead.Created_by = Users.ID
```

But this didn't work. What would be a correct statement so that I can pull the users names into the Lead VIEW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed a join to the Users table:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  Lead_detail 
  INNER JOIN Lead 
    ON Lead_detail.lead_id = Lead.id
  INNER JOIN Users
    ON Lead.Created_by = Users.ID
```